# How to get max on a column based on 2 other columns in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am quite new to power bi and I'm trying to work out how to get the following: 
I have a sales price table. It has Item numbers and location, with a date when price became effective. You could therefore have multiple rows per item number and location, but the correct price is the one with the latest date for that item and location.
Eg.
The table looks like this:

| Item No | Location | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I0090 | LOC1 | 20.94 | 2021/08/01 |
| I0090 | LOC1 | 22.00 | 2022/01/20 |
| I0090 | LOC1 | 23.34 | 2022/07/01 |
| I0090 | LOC2 | 21.33 | 2021/10/01 |
| I0090 | LOC2 | 22.22 | 2022/02/20 |
| I0090 | LOC2 | 23.56 | 2022/07/15 |

I need to get:

| Item No | Location | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I0090 | LOC1 | 23.34 | 2022/07/01 |
| I0090 | LOC2 | 23.56 | 2022/07/15 |

I.e. I need one row per item and location with the price for max date for each.
Please can someone help me with the correct query for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a custom column where you concatenate Item NO and Location
   [image: 1.]
2. Group by id and aggregate by max date
   [image: 2.a]
   [image: 2.b]
3. Developp the new column (where the tables are and check all the columns that you want, but make sure you select the date and price ones)
   [image: 3.]
4. Add custom column [date]=[ismaxdate] to create a boolean column
   [image: 4.]
5. Filter this new column when it's true
   [image: 5.]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table function to achieve your result:

Try this DAX Code:

```
Max_Price_Date =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE ( YourTbl, YourTbl[Item No], YourTbl[Location] ),
    "MaxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( YourTbl[Date] ) ),
    "Price", CALCULATE ( MAX ( YourTbl[Price] ), LASTDATE ( YourTbl[Date] ) )
)
```

Results the above mentioned code produces:

[image: GHF]

If you want to use it as a measure, create 2 new measures:

```
Max_Date_Measure =
VAR SummaryTbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTbl, YourTbl[Item No], YourTbl[Location] ),
        "MaxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( YourTbl[Date] ) ),
        "Price", CALCULATE ( MAX ( YourTbl[Price] ), LASTDATE ( YourTbl[Date] ) )
    )
VAR Result =
    MAXX ( SummaryTbl, [MaxDate] )
RETURN
    Result
```

Max Price Measure:

```
Max_Price_Measure =
VAR SummaryTbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTbl, YourTbl[Item No], YourTbl[Location] ),
        "MaxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( YourTbl[Date] ) ),
        "Price", CALCULATE ( MAX ( YourTbl[Price] ), LASTDATE ( YourTbl[Date] ) )
    )
VAR Result =
    MAXX ( SummaryTbl, [Price] )
RETURN
    Result
```

Then finally, create a table or matrix visual, Put [Item No] and [Location] columns on the rows, and put above measures in the values area. Here you go! Done!

Comment: Thanks! What is the equivalent of this in power query?

Comment: In Power Query, Dialect is the (M-Code). DAX is not the same as (M-Code); but obtaining the same result is almost always possible. I prefer to use DAX which I think is much faster.

Comment: @user11889334 I answered you about  how to do it in power query, please take a look and ask if you need more details